# Morrey growth condition implies Hölder continuity

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

It is know that the growth condition
$$\sup_{x \in \Omega }\int_{B_r(x)\cap \Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \leq C r^{n-2+2\alpha} \text{ 
for all } r>0$$
would imply that $u \in C^{0, \alpha}(\Omega)$.

I have read the book Multiple Integrals in the Calculus of Variations by Morrey. Since the book are old and hard to read, I can not find a theorem about that. May I have a reference about that?

Actually, I want to know when can I obtain the boundary regularity that $u \in C^{0, \alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$. So I want to take a look of the proof.

I want to know that would $\sup_{x \in \Omega}|\nabla u|$ implies $u \in C^{0, 1}(\overline{\Omega})$. May I have the reference about that also? Thank you!